# Ruby on rails rake db error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have cloned a project and ran it locally on my machine. I'm getting an error when i run `rake db:migrate`.

Can anyone please explain this to me? I have attached an image showing the error I am receiving.

[Error Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sa8N.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your rails gem, from 3.2.19 to 3.2.22.
You can edit your gemfile to look like this:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.22'
```

and then run

```
bundle update rails
```

Comment: LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.2/pg_ext
C:/Sites/zeeno/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/zeeno/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg_ext
C:/Sites/zeeno/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/zeeno/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: what is the version of `gem 'pg'` ?

Comment: 'pg', '0.12.2' this is the vesion

Comment: ok, you should reinstall this gem. First run `gem uninstall pg` and then install it with special flag: `gem install pg --pre`

Answer (score 0):

Try following command:

```
rake db:scheme:load
```

Comment: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
rake aborted!

Comment: same erro im getting